# Intellij IDEA workflow/shortcut to refactor codebase to replace method calls from one class to with method from another class

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA, what's the easiest way to replace method call from one class [`ClassA.doSomething(blah)`] with another class [`ClassB.doSomethingElse(blah)`]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `ClassA.doSomething(blah)` write `ClassB.doSomethingElse(blah)`, then `Refactor` | **Inline...** on `ClassA.doSomething(blah)`.